# String Include is not matching

Tags: ruby

I'm having an issue where a string link that has .pdf is not matching with include? in ruby. Example code

```
link = somelink.pdf
puts link.include?(".pdf")
```

Output when I run the program.

```
http://somelink.com/somepdf.pdf
false
```

Comment: `somelink.pdf.class` is probably not what you think it is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting to string first

```
link = somelink.pdf
puts link.to_s.include?(".pdf")
```

OR

```
File.extname(link.to_s) == ".pdf"
```

Comment: Ah, thanks. I can't believe I missed that. I'll accept it after ten minutes.